# Change icon folder when theres no option

Tags: icons, visual-studio

I want to change a icon for a Library, its Visual Studio 2015 folder.
But on properties therse's not the usual option to change the icon.
In other folders the option is shown as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to change a shortcut icon?

Try this:

1. Right-Click your shortcut and click properties:
   [image: shortcut-properties]
2. Click **Change Icon**.  You may see an error indicating no icons are available, or you may just see a blank pane where the icons should be:
   [image: no-icons]
3. Click **Browse** and navigate to an icon file, or a DLL / EXE file that contains icons.
4. You should then see icons populated in the selection pane:
   [image: icons-now-visible]